# How to replace text based on pattern?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have dataset called Vid1 that contains thousands of rows of data like the following:

```
SchoolName
----------
Johns Boys Varsity Football
Titan JV Football
East Central Varsity Basketball
Central Girls Basketball
```

Ideally, I want the data to look like this:

```
SchoolName
----------
Johns
Titan 
East Central
Central
```

I have tried using the following codes:

```
Vid1$SchoolName <- str_replace_all(Vid1$SchoolName, "Boys' [a-z,A-Z]*","")
Vid1$SchoolName <- str_replace_all(Vid1$SchoolName, "Varsity Football*", "")
Vid1$SchoolName <- str_replace_all(Vid1$SchoolName, " Basketball [a-z,A-Z]*","")
```

For some, the output is not ideal. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 0):

If *Johns, Titan, East Central and Central* are the only patterns you're interested in, you can do:

```
library(stringr)
patts = c('Boys', 'Titan', 'Central') # add patterns here
patts = str_flatten(collapse = '|')
Vid1$SchoolName = str_remove(Vid1$SchoolName, paste0('(?<=', patts, ').*'))
```

If there are more patterns you want to keep on the strings, you should add them to the `patts` vector.

Comment: they are not, there are over 50,000 rows of data. I guess i could allows find the most common words and go from there

Comment: you need to find patterns to be recognized by the regular expressions, then apply it to all the records on your table through a vectorized function, just like **str_remove()**. i edited the answer in a more generic way. then you can add the most convenient patterns for you

Answer (score 0):

You could try next approach with `stringi` defining a vector of words and their replace:

```
#Code
#Chains
chain<-c('Varsity','Football','JV','Girls','Basketball')
replace <- c('')
#Replace
trimws(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(df$V1, chain, replace, vectorize_all = FALSE))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Johns Boys"   "Titan"        "East Central" "Central"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared the exact rules to extract/remove the text keeping it open for us to interpret from the available data.

I have used the logic of removing two words from the text, one is the sports name and other one is the word before that. We can define variety of sports present in the data (for this example there are only 2) and paste them in one string and remove it using `sub`.

```
sports <- c('Football', 'Basketball')
regex_pattern <- sprintf('\\s\\w+\\s(%s)', paste0(sports, collapse = '|'))
sub(regex_pattern, '', Vid1$SchoolName)
#[1] "Johns Boys"   "Titan"        "East Central" "Central"
```

**data**

```
Vid1 <- structure(list(SchoolName = c("Johns Boys Varsity Football", 
"Titan JV Football","East Central Varsity Basketball", "Central Girls Basketball"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```